# Lemmatize a doc with spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I have a spaCy `doc` that I would like to lemmatize.

For example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

my_str = 'Python is the greatest language in the world'
doc = nlp(my_str)
```

How can I convert every token in the `doc` to its lemma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each token has a number of attributes, you can iterate through the doc to access them.

For example: `[token.lemma_ for token in doc]`

If you want to reconstruct the sentence you could use: `' '.join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])`

For a full list of token attributes see: https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes

Comment: So, does the lemmatizer automatically run when `doc` is called on a string?

Comment: By default yes. You can control which pipelines components are run by default, though I'm not sure where exactly lemmatization happens. https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#disabling

Comment: To add to polm23's comment, [this link in the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) shows the different components of the processing pipeline, and shows where lemmatization happens.

Answer (score 6):

If you **don’t need a particular component** of the pipeline – for example, the **NER** or the **parser**, you can disable loading it. This can sometimes make a big difference and **improve loading speed**.

For your case (Lemmatize a doc with spaCy) you only need the **tagger** component.

So here is a sample code:

```py
import spacy

# keeping only tagger component needed for lemmatization
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg',  disable=["parser", "ner"])

my_str = 'Python is the greatest language in the world'

doc = nlp(my_str)
words_lemmas_list = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]
print(words_lemmas_list)
```

Output:

> ['Python', 'be', 'the', 'great', 'language', 'in', 'the', 'world']

Comment: In case someone else reading this is wondering what the different components of the pipeline are (i.e. what can be enabled/disabled), [this link in the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) shows the different components of the processing pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This answer covers the case where your text consists of multiple sentences.

If you want to obtain **a list of all tokens being lemmatized**, do:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
my_str = 'Python is the greatest language in the world. A python is an animal.'
doc = nlp(my_str)

words_lemmata_list = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]
print(words_lemmata_list)
# Output: 
# ['Python', 'be', 'the', 'great', 'language', 'in', 'the', 'world', '.', 
# 'a', 'python', 'be', 'an', 'animal', '.']
```

If you want to obtain **a list of all sentences with each token being lemmatized**, do:

```
sentences_lemmata_list = [sentence.lemma_ for sentence in doc.sents]
print(sentences_lemmata_list)
# Output:
# ['Python be the great language in the world .', 'a python be an animal .']
```